# AVAudioPlayer not playing mp3 file

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I have run this app on my simulator as well as my phone and with multiple mp3 files however I cannot get sound to output from the app.  I have included the mp3 file in the supported files.  I am honestly lost as to what to do next.  I receive no errors however there is no audio.

```
@IBAction func play (sender: AnyObject){

func sharedInstance() {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        var song = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pingpong", ofType: "mp3")!)
        println(song)



        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: song, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
}
sharedInstance()

}
```

Comment: check if your phone is in silent mode.

Comment: The phone is not in silent mode for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your `var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` global for your class like shown in below code:

And I have modified your code to make it safe:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func play (sender: AnyObject){

        var categoryError: NSError?
        if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError) {
            println("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            var activateError: NSError?
            if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: &activateError) {
                println("AVAudioSession is Active")
                var song = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("we_cant_Stop", withExtension: "mp3")!
                var error:NSError?
                audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: song, error: &error)
                audioPlayer.play()

            } else if let activateError = activateError {
                println(activateError.description)
            }
        } else if let categoryError = categoryError {
            println(categoryError.description)
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine.